# My character can jump even when its not grounded

Tags: unity, c#

Here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //vars
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;

    Vector3 velocity;

    public float gravity = -9.81f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistanace = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;
    bool isGrounded;
    //-----------------------------------


    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistanace, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }



        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

character controller and etc

[image: picture]

[image: groundcheck inspector field]

[image: layers]

[image: groundcheck layers]

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured your character's collider, layer, `groundCheck` transform, and `groundMask` layers in your inspector?

Comment: The screenshot you've linked does not show the specific inspector fields I asked to see. Please edit your question to ensure that information is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that Physics.CheckSphere actually finds the capsule collider on the game object itself, which prevents it from ever returning false.

To prevent that either:

- Put the player and the ground on different [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and then pass a LayerMask to CheckSphere which excludes the player but includes the ground or
- Use [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) to get an array with all the colliders, and then check each collider to confirm that it is a collider you consider "ground".

Comment: Ok I will do thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Ok I found a half answer but still inconsistent

I lowered my groundcheck, but now when hitting the ground my "character" slows down when a bit above the ground and the space key only works when it wants too.